# RegisterStartupScript is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

i am new at ASP.NET and i got problem at using RegisterStartupScript.
i have one page with two UserControl. each UserControl have GridView that can display Detail Page, just like [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid).

here's the portion of my code:

SenderUserControl.ascx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowInsertFormSender() {
    window.radopen("WebfrmManageMemo.aspx?RefType=S", "UserListDialog");
    return false;
}
function refreshGridSender(arg) {
    if (!arg) {
        $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("RebindSender");
    }
    else {
        $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("RebindAndNavigateSender");
    }
}
function RowDblClickReceiver(sender, eventArgs) {
    window.radopen("WebfrmManageMemo.aspx?RefType=S&MemoID=" + eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("MemoID"), "UserListDialog");
}
```

ReceiverUserControl.ascx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowInsertFormReceiver() {
    window.radopen("WebfrmManageMemo.aspx?RefType=R", "UserListDialog");
    return false;
}
function refreshGridReceiver(arg) {
    if (!arg) {
        $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("RebindReceiverReferral");
    }
    else {
        $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("RebindAndNavigateReceiverReferral");
    }
}
function RowDblClickReceiver(sender, eventArgs) {
    window.radopen("WebfrmManageMemo.aspx?RefType=R&MemoID=" + eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("MemoID"), "UserListDialog");
}
```

DetailView.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseAndRebindSender(args) {
        GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.refreshGridSender(args);
        GetRadWindow().close();
    }

    function CloseAndRebindReceiver(args) {
        GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.refreshGridReceiver(args);
        GetRadWindow().close();
    }

    function GetRadWindow() {
        var oWindow = null;
        if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow; //Will work in Moz in all cases, including clasic dialog
        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; //IE (and Moz as well)

        return oWindow;
    }

    function CancelEdit() {
        GetRadWindow().close();
    }
</script>
```

DetailView.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["RefType"].ToString() == "S")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), GetType(), "closeSender", "CloseAndRebindSender('navigate');", true);
        }
        else if (Request["RefType"].ToString() == "R") 
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), GetType(), "closeReceiver", "CloseAndRebindReceiver('navigate');", true);
        }
    }
```

My problem is when i click button at DetailView.aspx,  `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), GetType(), "closeSender", "CloseAndRebindSender('navigate');", true);` is not working, but `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), GetType(), "closeReceiver", "CloseAndRebindReceiver('navigate');", true);` is working perfectly.

i have search on stackoverflow about why RegisterStartupScript is not working and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994040/scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-code-not-working-why), but i didn't see something is wrong with my code.

is there anything i miss?
Please help. Thank you

Comment: Any Error messages ?

Comment: no error message. when i click the button to trigger `closeSender` just nothing happened.

Comment: is it satisfied RefType == S condition ? Then put a debugger on CloseAndRebindSender function

Comment: i'm using javascript debugger and i got error at `RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID` in `refreshGridSender`. The error is 'ajaxManager' is null or not an object. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

i've got the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334571/ajaxmanager-not-found-null).
the problem is with the javascript in Sender.ascx.
i don't know what's going on but i solved it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the `Sys.Application.Load` event when working with IScriptControls, as accessing them in earlier client-side events will give you null. Here is an article on the matter: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-javascript-from-server-side.html.